# How do I load jQuery in external libraries for WebStorm?

Tags: javascript

I was testing this and that to import jsQuery in my js file.

I tried to 
    *npm install -g jquery
    , npm install jquery --save
    , npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
    , npm i jquery --save* and *WebStorm-Setting-Javascript-Libraries-Download jquery* to adjust to manage scope in my js file, then added directory to External Libraries */@types/jquery*.

But I still can't load jquery in my js code.

for example,

```
import $ from 'jquery'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier


import $ from '@types/jquery'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier


import jquery;
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier


var $ = require('jquery');

Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'


jQuery.get();
^

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to import jquery in my file. What I need to load jquery?

Comment: open `node_modules` and check if jquery is downloaded properly

Comment: Oh. There is no jquery in **node_moudules** of my project. How can I download this directory? Is it able to  download through npm instruction?

Comment: check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: I realized that directory jquery installed is windows..omg. Thank you for your advice